# Liquibase adding comments for already existing tables / columns

Tags: oracle, liquibase

is there a way to add comments for already existing tables using xml liquibase files? Using Liquibase with oracle db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the existing change tags allow this, but it would be fairly straightforward to write a new change tag.

Comment: Decided to just use sql files and attach them to changeset.